# What is this? (within a 3d model)

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, geometry

Exploring the inside of a model, I find these curious red lines. Could someone tell me what they are and what purpose they have please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title for your questions. Also please do some research before posting

Comment: Sorry about that. I found out that my post is duplicated, so how do I delete it then?

Comment: No need to delete, it may help others in the future find similar answers

Answer (score 1):

Those are Marked Seams for UVs

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much for the information.